# Are these sentences grammatically accurate?

Tags: grammaticality

> Half the people who are interested in me, are people I'm not interested in.

Would it be grammatically correct if the above sentence was shortened to:

> Half the people who're interested in me, I'm not interested in.

---

Is this sentence grammatically correct:

> The guy who loves me, I don't love back.

Comment: Could you isolate the problem you're asking about? The way it stands, this question is essentially a proofreading request.

Comment: No, it would be ungrammatical to omit the object of preposition **in** there.You could say *Half the people you are interested in, I'm not.*  Do you understand why?